# Spin a FontAwesome icon along with page scrolling

Tags: scroll, font-awesome

I want to spin the `<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>` icon as the page is scrolled down (up). I mean as long as you scroll down (up) the page the icon will be spinning right or left with the speed depending on the scroll speed. Seems like I want too much, but it would be awesome if there were some ready solutions out there.

Answer (score 1):

Up vs down will take some extra code, speed is not possible using font awesome spin, so I would do that something like this to get you as close as possible:

```
var timer;     
$(window).scroll(function(e){
         clearTimeout(timer);
         $('.fa-refresh').addClass('fa-spin');
         timer = setTimeout(checkStop,150);
 });

function checkStop(){
  $('.fa-refresh').removeClass('fa-spin');
}
```

[Heres working example in FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/A6Vme/35/)

just keep scrolling up and down to see it spin